# How to pass data via Intent in Realm

Tags: android, android-intent, realm

I want to know that how to pass data via intent in the realm. in [this example](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-realm-database-replacing-sqlite-core-data/www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-realm-database-replacing-sqlite-core-data/) he is using alertDialog but if we want to start new activity then how to load that data in the new activity?

Comment: This section in the docs might be helpful: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#intents

Comment: @AmitKhatkar that example you linked is an atrocity, I rewrote that here: https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-book-example

Answer (score 0):

You should send the primary key of the object through the bundle, and requery the object in the new Activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this /*activity*/, OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("personId", person.getId());
startActivity(intent);
```

And

```
public class OtherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Realm realm;
    Person person;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        person = realm.where(Person.class)
                      .equalTo(PersonFields.ID, getIntent().getLongExtra("personId"))
                      .findFirst();
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

---

You can read more about basic FAQ questions like that either in [the official documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#intents), or in my [Medium article series](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/basics-of-realm-a-guide-to-using-realm-1-2-0-634471c0fe8f#.sszya563c).

Comment: Very nice answer))) Put realm into activity, and send intent to activity)) This is the most non-standard thinking which I ever seen :-)

Comment: You should definetely not use Activity for that - IntentService or Service is fine, but Activity is supposed to be used with UI